# display php mssql query array in html table

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I'm a total amateur with php.  I've tried dozens of different things, mostly found while browsing around here. I've been at it for hours, and I'm starting to lose my mind. Lacking real knowledge I'm just guessing at this point.

I'm positive this code is completely butchered and will be highly offensive to many of you.

The goal is to display the mssql query results into a nice HTML table. 
So far, nothing is displaying except the table headers. The query should return dozens of rows.

Here's the current code, any suggestions?

```php
<?php
// Open db connection
$dbc = mssql_connect('host', 'sa', 'password');
if (!$dbc || !mssql_select_db('dbname', $dbc)) {die('Unable to connect or select database!');}

// Select queries
$query = mssql_query("SELECT [name],[customer],[start_time],[end_time],[status] FROM dbo.reservation ORDER BY last_update DESC");

// display the results!
if (!mssql_num_rows($query)) {
    echo 'No records found';
} else {
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($query)) {
                echo'<tr>'; 
                echo'<td>'. $row['name']."</td>";
                echo'<td>'. $row['customer'].'</td>';
                echo'<td>'. $row['start_time'].'</td>';
                echo'<td>'. $row['end_time'].'</td>';
                echo'<td>'. $row['status'].'</td>';
                echo'<tr>';
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

Note: This is for an internal site and I need to use mssql_connect.

Comment: Sounds like your query is not returning any data. Suggest using `var_dump($query)` to see just what you are getting back.

Comment: that returns: resource(3) of type (mssql result). Not sure what that means.  Also, if I run the same query in MSSQL, I get results back.

Comment: Well, that sounds like you got three result rows. I think your problem is that you are using `mssql_fetch_row()` when what you really want is [`mssql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to index the result row from `mssql_fetch_row()` with column names, but this function only returns an array with numeric indices. Use [`mssql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php) to get an array that you can index with column names.

Comment: Great! Now you should accept the answer - as the one who asked the question you should see a checkmark below the up and down arrows  next to the answer - click on that to indicate that this answer worked for you. If you ask a question and get multiple answers you should accept the one that you think is best.